# How does the "Akimbo Ace" skill stack with the Hitman perk deck's "Tooth and Claw" perk?

Tags: payday-2

The Fugitive skill tree's "Akimbo Ace" skill and the Hitman perk deck's "Tooth and Claw" perk modifies the same Akimbo weapon-related stats:

> *Tooth and Claw*
> Your stability penalty with Akimbo weapons is set to 50% and
> increases the ammo capacity of your Akimbo weapons to 125%.
>
> *Akimbo Ace*
> Your stability penalty with Akimbo weapons is set to 25% and increases
> the ammo capacity of your Akimbo weapons to 150%.

The game previously had a bug where the ["Walk-in Closet" perk would override the "Fully Loaded Ace"](http://steamcommunity.com/games/218620/announcements/detail/221002055299683127) skill, despite the latter giving better bonuses to the same stat. I am wondering if "Tooth and Claw", and "Akimbo Ace" currently have a similar issue. If not, how do their stability and ammo capacity bonuses stack?

Comment: your best bet to test this would be to simply switch to a different perk tree and start a heist with akimbo active and check the ammo. then try with the perk active. if the ammo is decreased because of the perk I would say its safe to assume that the perk overrides the skill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly it doesn't I've tried this myself a week or two ago and no it doesn't grant you any additional bonuses, it seems that you can only have one or the other, despite the fact that you have two effects doing similar things. So you're better off either having the perk deck activated or having the Akimbo skill aced.